# Windows IoT Core on Raspberry PI default webserver

Tags: webserver, windows-10-iot-core

Have someone found how to make a similar webserver as the default IoT Core one? The most similar example found is [this](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2016/04/08/building-a-windows-10-iot-core-background-webserver/) but when I try to insert some javascript in the page, is not recognized. In the default webserver of the IoT Core there are a lot of js and jQuery scripts that runs very well.
Someone have ideas please?
Thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2016/04/08/building-a-windows-10-iot-core-background-webserver/) sample, you can add a HTML file to your project and use this HTML file host the content of the web page, then insert some javascript in it.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Background Message</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello from the background process!<br />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myVariable = 'Hello, I come from script!';
    window.alert(myVariable);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You need edit part of code like this:

```
                    using (var response = output.AsStreamForWrite())
                    {
                        string page = "";

                        var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
                        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("index.html");
                        var readFile = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
                        foreach (var line in readFile)
                        {
                            page += line;
                        }
                        page += query;

                        byte[] bodyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(page);
                        var bodyStream = new MemoryStream(bodyArray);

                        var header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                        $"Content-Length: {bodyStream.Length}\r\n" +
                        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
                        byte[] headerArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

                        await response.WriteAsync(headerArray, 0, headerArray.Length);
                        await bodyStream.CopyToAsync(response);
                        await response.FlushAsync();
                    }
```

After deploying your app to Raspberry Pi, while the app running, you can visit the web server. The result will look like this:

[image]